# Symfony3 New and Edit Controller Logic

Tags: php, symfony

In an administration backend, I want to provide the following functionality:

- A user should be able to create a recipe with a simple form
- A user can view an existing recipe directly rendered in a form, so changes can be made and the form can be saved

I believe this is a trivial task. I created entity and form type, but I am completely blank on how to the Controller should behave.

Here is my Controller:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

// use statements...

class RecipeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/recipes", name="recipe_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request) : Response
    {
        // code to fetch paginated list of recipes
        // and render it
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/admin/recipes/new", name="recipe_new")
     * @Method("POST")
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request) : Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(RecipeType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $recipe = $form->getData();
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($recipe);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $this->addFlash(
                'success',
                'Recipe successfully added!');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('recipe_index');
        }

        return $this->render('Admin/recipe_form.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/admin/recipes/{id}", name="recipe_detail")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Recipe $recipe) : Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(RecipeType::class,$recipe);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $recipe = $form->getData();
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($recipe);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $this->addFlash(
                'success',
                'Recipe successfully updated!');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('recipe_index');
        }

        return $this->render('Admin/recipe_form_edit.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'recipe' => $recipe
        ]);
    }
}
```

There are several problems with this approach:

- code duplication in the create and update methods
- code duplication in the corresponding twig templates

As the create and update form do not differ, I wonder how I can reuse the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected few things in your code: you don't need to persist when updating a form, you don't need to add your object when editing the form, the form already has the data. You can use the same template and same form for both views.

```
class RecipeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/recipes", name="recipe_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request) : Response
    {
        // code to fetch paginated list of recipes
        // and render it

    }
/**
 * @Route("/admin/recipes/new", name="recipe_new")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{

    $recipe = new Recipe();
    $form = $this->createForm(RecipeType::class, $recipe);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($recipe);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'Recipe successfully added!');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('recipe_index');
    }

    return $this->render('Admin/recipe_form.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/admin/recipes/{id}", name="recipe_detail")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Recipe $recipe) : Response
{

    $form = $this->createForm(RecipeType::class,$recipe);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        // No need to persist, the object is already persisted, just flush
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'Recipe successfully updated!');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('recipe_index');
    }

// You don't need to use the recipe_form_edit, you can use the one you created above
    return $this->render('Admin/recipe_form.html.twig', [
// Form already has its values filled-in no need to add the entity
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
    }
}
```